# How to avoid rounded edges and thick black border of modal panel?

Tags: css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am showing a modal panel whenever a button/panel is tapped. My problem is look and feel of this modal panel because I don't want round edges and thick black border on this panel because rest of my app has thin borders and sharp edges. here is fiddle of something similar : http://www.senchafiddle.com/#0RPKU

Is there a property of panel which I can change to avoid this? If not can you give me CSS example which can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty way add the following line into your popup panel definition:

```
style: '-webkit-border-radius: 0; border-radius: 0;'
```

If you want something cleaner - go with SachinG approach - create your own CSS class, add it to each panel, but the key CSS difference remains `border-radius`.

Comment: Thanks! Here is the fiddle for people who are looking for final results: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#gvnpz#35DTe

Answer (score 1):

In the example fiddle you give you would need to change the `padding` css property.

Comment: Okay and how to fix rounded edges?

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner approach would be to define your own styles in custom class and set to modal panel. That way you'll be having all the control over appearance. You don't have to worry about positioning the modal in correct place that because behavior does not get affected.

Like-

```
  .some{
        border: 1px solid #000;           
        background: #fff;
        color:#ff8100;
        font-family: verdana;
        ...
    }
```

and add this class as `baseCls:'some'` to modal panel. I personally don't like adding inline styles and stuff. I wish there could be a `config` option for such thing like `ui` config options. But `ui` config does not work with `panel`s i guess.